# Can Google assistant on one device be commanded from another device both of which have been signed into the same Google Account?

Tags: sms, google-account, google, google-assistant

User has two android devices(phones). User has signed into the *`same google account`* on both devices.

**Device01:**
 - Work Device
 - Has a sim card
 - Mobile data enabled
 - Is not used much, kept away while at home
 - Hotspot is switched on while at home.

**Device02:**
 - Play device
 - Doesn't have a sim card
 - Always used by the user while at user home
 - Gets data connection through WiFi of Device01/Public WiFi

**Consider the following senario:**
 - The user is watching YouTube on `Device02` in another room / goes out to buy a pack of chips,
 - User wants to send a SMS real quick,
 - Now can the user ask his google assistant on `Device02` *"Okay Google, Send SMS to Mr. XYZ"* and set up google assistant such that SMS is sent through `Device01` instead?

Is this currently possible? Or will we need Google Nest/Hub/Home etc...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do that, because device 1 has a simcard and device 2 has internet connection only, but you can text device 1 using whatsapp or telegram

Comment: I think I didn't ask the question properly... I don't want to text from `device2 to device1`; I want to ask assistant in `Dev2` to connect to assistant in `Dev1` and send sms **from Dev1** to some third party...